# Differential Signals (LVDS)

Tags: common-mode, lvds

Talking about diff  signals, we hear that they carry equal & opposite voltage. How will I conclude that referring the figure below :-

[image]

What is the significance of common mode voltage in diff signals. Also, what are VoH & voL meant for??

Comment: The answers to this old question apply: [What does common mode voltage stand for in an instrumentation amplifier?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91756/what-does-common-mode-voltage-stand-for-in-an-instrumentation-amplifier)

Comment: I agree but I needed more basic explanation.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the significance of common mode voltage in diff signals.

The common mode voltage is the average of the voltage of the two components of the differential signal. Ideally it doesn't vary when the signal is in a logical '1' or '0' state.

It is important to know the common mode voltage because different receivers might have different ranges of acceptable input common mode voltage and you want to know that your transmitter and receiver are compatible.

> Also, what are VoH & voL meant for??

V<sub>OH</sub> and V<sub>OL</sub> are exactly what they are defined to be in your graph: the voltage levels that the signals switch between, depending whether the signal is a logical '1' or '0'.

Again, you might need to know these levels to determine if your differential transmitter and receiver are compatible. For example, you wouldn't want V<sub>OH</sub> to exceed the maximum instantaneous input voltage of your receiver.

The difference between V<sub>OH</sub> and V<sub>OL</sub> also tells you the amplitude of your signal. Sometimes you might need to check these values to know if the signal amplitude specified elsewhere is a differential or single-ended amplitude.

> where does the equal & opposite voltage be specified in this figure.

If you subtract off the common-mode voltage from each component signal, then they will be equal and opposite.

If the two components are \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$, whenever \$V_A\$ is at \$V_{CM}+0.175\$ then \$V_B\$ is at \$V_{CM}-0.175\$ and vice versa.

Comment: Cleared 50% of my doubts. Thanks for that. If the 2 signals of diff pair are defined by VoH & VoL, where does the equal & opposite voltage be specified in this figure i.e V+ & V-??

Comment: VOH is Voltage Out (High). VOL is Voltage Out (Low).

Comment: The datasheet of SNSAS2150 from Pericom says supply voltage as 3.3V. but nothing is mentioned as common mode voltage. How to take common mode value??

Comment: Since they specify V_OH and V_OL you can estimate that the common mode voltage is about half-way between those values. But the V_OH and V_OL values alone should be enough to determine compatibility with another PECL part.

Comment: Note that your question title asks about LVDS, and this part is not LVDS, it is PECL. PECL and LVDS are two different logic standards.

Comment: Wanted to add PECL but no tag is available for PECl & added LVDS to take ref of another diff logic.

Comment: Does supply voltage & common mode voltage has any relation other than that supply V will always be larger than common mode voltage!!    Also, receiver datasheet says the input differential amplitude should be between 0.18V to 2V. Is it the voltage swing i.e. (V+ - V-)??