# Unclear common-mode voltage specs in the DMS-20LCD volt-panel-meter

Tags: common-mode

I would like to buy a small digital volt-panel-meter. My eye fell on this series from Murata:

> **DMS-20LCD** (https://www.murata-ps.com/data/meters/20lcd.pdf)

This meter can be powerd by either a 5V supply or 9V battery.

The datasheet limits the **Common Mode Voltage Range** to +/-2V on the second page, but no further explanation is given.
Page 4 in the datasheet mentions the Common Mode Voltage again in the first application example:

---

[image]

---

When I see the picture, I would say:

- `Vcm = 2.5V`
- `Vin- = 2.5V - 0.833V`
- `Vin+ = 2.5V + 0.833V`

Since `Vcm = 2.5V`, it is outside the +/-2V range. Why would Murata give an example which doesn't meet its own specs? I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: Here must be the answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/91764/80284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your dilemma. Firstly, yes, you are quite right that strictly-speaking, the common mode voltage on the diagram is 2.5 volts but you could also make an argument that it is 1.667 volts with a signal of +1.667 volts on pin 11.

I think this is what they mean although by no means is this clear in their document. In other words, make sure pin 12 remains within +/-2 volts if you want accuracy.

Comment: Thank you sir.
Their document is so ... unclear :-(.   
So `pin 12` should remain within +/- 2 volts. What are the limits on `pin 11`?

Comment: That is how I read the situation. If your meter has a +/- 200 mV range then pin 11 has to be within +/-200 mV of pin 12 or you will reach full-scale limitations. It won't damage the device but you run out of measurement capability. If your input can measure +/- 200 volts then pin 11 can be as high as 202 volts or as low as -202 volts at extremes of the limitation imposed on pin 12.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you sir. You seem to have lots of experience (almost 200k)! Which panel meter would you suggest? I need 6 small panel meters, preferably ones that I can solder on a board :-). They need to measure the voltages of Li-ion cells (6 serial connected cells).

Comment: I'm building a test-setup, and need to keep an eye on all the individual cell voltages :-)

Comment: I have NO experience of panel meters! I've never used one or chosen one.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry sir :-)