# Output Voltage Minimum Limit of LM358 as Error Amplifer

Tags: operational-amplifier, biasing, error-amplifier

I am using one side of the LM358 as an error amplifier with a gain of 1, biased according to [this MIT lesson](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/media-arts-and-sciences/mas-836-sensor-technologies-for-interactive-environments-spring-2011/readings/MITMAS_836S11_read02_bias.pdf) for differential amplifiers.

[image: LM358 Error Amplifier with Offset]

The results below show me tuning the reference signal to see if I get the desired output error. My error = SENSE + OFFSET - REF. It appears to saturate at an output voltage (the error signal) of 500mV.

[image: LM358 Biased EA, dynamic REF, SENSE set to 1V]

Why is this? I've checked the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf) I have for the LM358 but cannot seem to make sense of the operating limitations, since this shows the output voltage conditions with a load attached (I am operating with no load):

[image: LM358 Output Voltage Limitations, with load]

What am I missing? Where on the datasheet can I find information about the minimum output voltage?

My supply is +5V to GND, so I expected the output to reach zero and stay there when my calculated error reached the negative zone.

Comment: Look on a block diagram (usually in data sheet) at the output transistor arrangement inside the opamp. Pull down capability is limited. Try adding a load to ground. The LM358 is NOT a "rail to rail" amplifier even though it is at least notionally single supply.  A whiff of negative supply relative to ground can help muchly. A Heath Robinson but sometimes useful 'fix' is a diode in the nehative power lead with ground at diode anode and Vdd of opamp at diode cathode - about 0.6V below ground. Place a decoupling cap across the diode. You now have Vcc ~~= 4.3V and Vee = ~~-0.6V wrt ground.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thank you for your input. Looking at the FBD it is not immediately apparent that the pull down capability is limited.

I understand that it is not a rail-to-rail amplifier, but a minimum VOUT of 0.5 is still 10% of the supply, which I figured was far too much. 

Without having the capability to supply a negative VCC instead of ground, you are suggesting the diode solution, correct? (Note: there is no drain supply, Vdd, on the opamp, just Vcc)

Comment: I believe you are attempting to mix 3 voltages but superposition does not apply to the + input , which sees two voltage R dividers that load each other while you could be saturating your output. WHere is U1A out data? Was it noise free?

Comment: Hi @TonyStewartEEsince1975, thank you for your input. I am only mixing two voltages at the + input : OFFSET (also written as BIAS) + SENSE, and this appears to work because my actual ERROR signal matches my calculated error. It also worked in simulation.

As for the data for the U1A, that is my LM358. I did attach the datasheet and included a snippet of the output voltage limitations section, which is the area of interest. 

Yes, these signals were noise free, from what I could see on the scope.

Comment: At low Voit and low Vdifferential at high Vdd values the LM358 will sink 12 uA worst case. Datasheets [**TI**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf) - [**Fairchild**](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM258A.pdf) - [**OnSemi**](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM258A.pdf). Typical values are higher BUT Murphy doesn't care.  With R4 = 10k, 12 uA = 0.12V. Exactly what you need depends on the inverting input voltage BUT at low Vout the LM358 clearly gets 'rather wimpy'.

Comment: My "diode trick" to generate -Vee of about 0.6V is not overly nice bt will help the LM358 around ground. Be aware that the max common mode Vin is 1.5V below Vcc = 3.5V at Vcc=5V and about 2.9V when the diode is used. || The LM358 is a very very very old opamp and while it is incredibly useful for many tasks you run up against it's limitations in situations like this. There are far better more modern opamps at not vast cost. Where are you located? (ie easy to get other components or not).

Comment: Thanks for your comments @RussellMcMahon. I am limited to the LM358 because I am based in a lab in Dhaka and that's what we have a large stock of. As for the CMV, if 3.5V is my limit, I am nowhere near that limit in my tests.

For instance, at the part where my error accuracy stops, the differential voltage is 0.44V, and I would guess that the CMV is 1.8V? Do you "measure" the CMV by the voltage that the two signals share? Using this as my reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91756/what-does-common-mode-voltage-stand-for-in-an-instrumentation-amplifier

Comment: CMV is usually taken as the mean of the differential input signals. For large differential voltage it's safer to use the higher of the two when the upper limit is being considered. Try halving the value of the two Rs connected to opamp pin 2 - say to 4K7 each and see how / if it affects the results. | You can test my claim re LM358 drive at low Vout and low Vdifferential by measuring the voltage that it can support across a given resistor.